# set background color of single ListView element and forget it when the new element is clicked [Android]

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I know how to change a background color of single listView item but i want to if the another row will be clicked, the color of previous element dissapeared and reappeared in to newly selected item.

It's my method:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);      
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#222222"));
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Save the reference to the last view that you've clicked. Then when you click on the view, change the background of the last one, and assign the last view to the current one that you just clicked.

Answer (score 1):

not tested but still try it

```
//reset all the listView items background colours before we set the clicked one..

        for (int i=0; i<l.getChildCount(); i++) 
        {
            l.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);      
        }
        //and then reset color for single row
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#222222"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this question. Maybe somebody will use it.

```
private void changeChoosenRowSettings(ListView l, int position) {
        l.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        if (save != -1 && save != position){
            l.getChildAt(save).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        save = position;

    }
```